# How do I add a specific property to a font?

Tags: c#, colors, richtextbox, rtf, text-formatting

I have a string formatting system in place in which users can use special character combinations to color text, add bold, italics, and underlines, all on a text-centered basis.

My problem is, when a user tries to bold AND underline something, for example, the text only displays the latter property. for example,

```
{bold char combo}{italic char combo}Hello, World
```

Would show up as:

*Hello, World*

Rather than:

***Hello, World***

Here's an example of the code i'm currently using.

```cs
// Other formatting codes...
case 'B': // Bold
   box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
   break;
case 'I': // Italic
   box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Italic);
   break;
// Other formatting codes...
```

Comment: Note: you use "font" in the original sense (a family of typographic characters, which are made together, same design). But the modern/computer use is to use just for one set of character. So your question is "how to select a font with specific properties" (maybe adding " from a font family"). Keep it mind, it will simplify the keyword selection when using Google.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Understandable. I'll keep that in mind next time I come across a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution.

```cs
box.SelectionFont = new Font(box.SelectionFont, box.SelectionFont.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
```

Adapted from ["A way to overcome RichTextBox's limitations?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3089866/a-way-to-overcome-richtextboxs-limitations)